# JDBC driver not found, even after placing its jar in Tomcat home /lib folder, when run in Netbeans 8

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans, jdbc

When using Tomcat 8 to run my Servlets while programming in NetBeans 8 under Java 8, I placed my JDBC driver jar in the correct location: Tomcat's home holder, in its `/lib` folder, amongst the *catalina.jar* and *servlet-api.jar* and such.

When trying to run, NetBeans shows errors saying the JDBC driver cannot be found.

I tried both the *Build* button and the *Clean & Build* button.

I tried manually deleting contents of the `Private Configuration Folder (Catalina Base)` folder that I had established when configuring the connection between NetBeans & Tomcat.

I tried quitting and restarting NetBeans.

Why is my JDBC jar not found?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You need to remove that Tomcat configuration from NetBeans. Then recreate that configuration.

## Explanation

Apparently when first run from NetBeans, a list of jar files in that `/lib` folder is somehow recorded. **Jars added later are ignored**.

## Details

You can verify this list by examining the NetBeans↔Tomcat configuration’s properties.

To access properties, context-click the Tomcat server’s item in NetBeans `Services` > `Servers` list. Choose `Properties`.

[image: screen shot of NetBeans > Services panel > Servers > Tomcat configuration item > Properties (menu item)]

Click the `Classes` tab to see a list of jars known from the Tomcat `/lib` folder. The two JDBC driver jars shown here did *not* appear when I first dropped them into `/lib`. They appeared only after removing and re-creating the NetBeans↔Tomcat configuration.

[image: screen shot of Services panel > Servers > Tomcat configuration item > Properties > Servers (window) > Classes (tab)]

To remove the NetBeans↔Tomcat configuration, context-click the Tomcat server's item in NetBeans `Services` > `Servers` list. Choose `Remove`.

[image: screen shot of Services panel > Servers > Tomcat configuration item > Remove]

Re-create the Tomcat configuration by context-clicking the `Servers` grouping, and choose `Add Server…`.

[image: screen shot of NetBeans > Services panel > Servers > Add Server (menu item)]

Now you can check the `Properties` > `Classes` again, and you'll see any extra jars added now appear in the list. Your JDBC driver will now be available to your servlets.

---

Aside: I found that NetBeans was cranky about my re-using the previous `Private Configuration Folder (Catalina Base)` folder. I had to manually delete the folder from the file system (the Finder on a Mac), create a new folder in the same place, and pasted to give the new folder the same old name.